# Vertically Align CheckBox of CheckboxTableCell

Tags: css, javafx

I am creating a table with expandable rows in JavaFX based on this example:

http://codemonkeycorner.com/post/expandable-table-rows-in-javafx

I am also adding a CheckBoxTableCell in the simplest possible manner:

```
TableColumn<Person, Boolean> checkBoxCol = new TableColumn<>("check");

checkBoxCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(itemId -> {
    BooleanProperty visibleProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    return visibleProperty;
}));
table.getColumns().addAll(expandCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, checkBoxCol);
```

This works well for adding the CheckBoxes, however when I expand the table rows the checkbox will be vertically aligned to the center of the expanded row instead of stying at the top which is the behavior of the text cells.

[image]

Is there a way to change this behavior using CSS or Java code? How can I set the vertical alignment of the CheckBox within the CheckBoxTableCell?

Comment: [mcve] please .. here, not a link to anywhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply in the CSS for the checkbox element cell the property "vertical-align:middle;"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, setting

```
-fx-alignment: top-center;
```

in CSS worked.